# Can't see attachments in OWA but can in Outlook

Tags: exchange, outlook-web-app, attachment

I have several users, including myself, that cannot see attached images (.jpg) in OWA.  I can see them in Outlook but in OWA the attachments, the link to see them, are not included.  I see the line for attachments in the message.  But it's just empty.  I have other messages that have been sent to me from outside of the domain and I can see them.  Just not internally sent ones.  Was hoping for help.  Thank you.

I did not see anything in the file levels of the registry to prohibit .jpg files.

Exchange 2003 Server, Outlook 2003, OWA for 2003.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Firefox (or even if not) and do you have any add-ons that could be blocking this

If not, I would go to the Exchange server and check the OWA settings, or downloading the OWA admin pack and make sure no weird options are set.